# Why Max and Position do not work with NumberForm?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

```
dats = Flatten@
   ParallelTable[
    NumberForm[RandomReal[], {3, 5}], {i, -4, 5, 1}, {j, 73}];
```

Then finding the max. value does not work

```
Max@dats
```

Similarly, if I want to find the position of an element

```
In[345]:= dats[[1]]

0.00089
```

The `Position` is not working too

```
In[346]:= Position[dats, 0.33900]

Out[346]= {}
```

Comment: Look at the `TreeForm` for a `NumberForm` object; and try: `Max[dats[[All, 1]]]`

Comment: For searching: `Position[dats[[All, 1]], 0.05001168909146414`]` in my case gives: `{{20}}`. I had to manually copy and paste to get full precision.

Comment: @Syed, but that destroys number form like to keep.. I need the output of `data` in `0.00000`  and when searching use this form only.

Comment: I tried `SetAccuracy` and it works now with `Max` but not for `Position`

Comment: The idea (as I understand it so far) is to let Mathematica handle the numbers internally and format these at the end for display/reporting purposes. May I ask why you would like to use such functionality? Searching for an exact real number is not very useful and results in non-portable code. Usually inequality operators are used.

Comment: I have data with too many significance numbers e.g  `0.0000000000000000000` and I am interested, say,  in the first four `0.0000`. First I would like to chop this data and then do some calculations that include finding maxima and locating specific points. So how can I restructure such data, please?

Comment: @valarmorghulis it seems to me that you should `Round` your numbers first, rather than using NumberForm. Note that the `*Form` functions are invariably display wrappers and often interfere with further computation.

Comment: Could apply `NumberForm` after you have found the desired value and position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, `NumberForm` is a wrapper. E.g.,

```
SeedRandom[314];
dats = Flatten@Table[NumberForm[RandomReal[], {3, 5}], {i, -4, 5, 1}, {j, 73}];
dats[[1]] // FullForm  (* NumberForm[0.9589271300722904`,List[3,5]] *)
```

So if you want the biggests, you can try `MaximalBy[dats, First]`.

On the other hand, if you round, then things work more how you seem to want.

```
SeedRandom[314];
dats2 = Flatten@Table[Round[RandomReal[], 0.00001], {i, -4, 5, 1}, {j, 73}];
dats2[[1]] // FullForm  (* 0.9589300000000001` *)
Position[dats2, 0.95893]   (* {{1}} *)
Max[dats2]  (* 0.99967 *)
Position[dats2, 0.99967]  (* {{209}} *)
```